# How do I link to external THUMB code?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, ld, thumb

I'm writing THUMB code for an embedded core (ARM7TDMI) that needs to be linked to existing THUMB code. I'm using the GNU ARM embedded toolchain ([link](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)). I cannot get the linker to treat the existing external code as THUMB; it seems to always think that it's ARM. The existing code that I'm linking to is absolutely static and cannot be changed/recompiled (it's a plain binary sitting on a ROM chip, basically).

Here is an example program, `multiply.c`, that demonstrates the issue:

```
extern int externalFunction(int x);
int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    return externalFunction(x * y);
}
```

Compiled using:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o multiply.o -c -O3 multiply.c -march=armv4t -mtune=arm7tdmi -mthumb
arm-none-eabi-ld -o linked.o multiply.o -T symbols.txt
```

Where `symbols.txt` is a simple linker script:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text 0x8000000 : { *(.text) }
}
externalFunction = 0x8002000;
```

When I `objdump -d linked.o`, I get:

```
08000000 <multiply>:
 8000000:       b510            push    {r4, lr}
 8000002:       4348            muls    r0, r1
 8000004:       f000 f804       bl      8000010 <__externalFunction_from_thumb>
 8000008:       bc10            pop     {r4}
 800000a:       bc02            pop     {r1}
 800000c:       4708            bx      r1
 800000e:       46c0            nop                     ; (mov r8, r8)

08000010 <__externalFunction_from_thumb>:
 8000010:       4778            bx      pc
 8000012:       46c0            nop                     ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000014:       ea0007f9        b       8002000 <externalFunction>
```

Instead of branching directly to 0x8002000, it branches to a stub that switches to ARM mode first and then branches to 0x8002000 in ARM mode. I want that BL to branch directly to 0x8002000 and stay in THUMB mode, so that I'd get this instead:

```
08000000 <multiply>:
 8000000:       b510            push    {r4, lr}
 8000002:       4348            muls    r0, r1
 8000004:       ???? ????       bl      8002000 <__externalFunction>
 8000008:       bc10            pop     {r4}
 800000a:       bc02            pop     {r1}
 800000c:       4708            bx      r1
```

ABI and calling convention issues aside, how do I achieve this?

Comment: The obvious thing to try would be `externalFunction = 0x8002001;`.

Comment: I get the same output as before using `0x8002001`: it actually gets assembled with the bit cleared. It seems _very_ committed to making sure it's an ARM call...

Comment: There seems to be a reported bug about this, https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15302, but unfortunately the fix for it only applies to Thumb only targets which you don't appear to be using. If you don't mind a non-linker script solution, you could do: `static int (* const externalFunction)(int x) = (int (*)(int)) 0x80002001;`

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is make it do what you want

branchto.s

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.globl branchto
branchto:
    bx r0
```

so.c

```
extern unsigned int externalFunction;
extern int branchto ( unsigned int, int );
int fun ( int x )
{
    return(branchto(externalFunction,x)+3);
}
```

so.ld

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text 0x8000000 : { *(.text) }
}
externalFunction = 0x8002001;
```

producing

```
08000000 <fun>:
 8000000:   4b04        ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; (8000014 <fun+0x14>)
 8000002:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
 8000004:   0001        movs    r1, r0
 8000006:   6818        ldr r0, [r3, #0]
 8000008:   f000 f806   bl  8000018 <branchto>
 800000c:   3003        adds    r0, #3
 800000e:   bc10        pop {r4}
 8000010:   bc02        pop {r1}
 8000012:   4708        bx  r1
 8000014:   08002001    stmdaeq r0, {r0, sp}

08000018 <branchto>:
 8000018:   4700        bx  r0
```

Ross Ridge's solution in the comments works

```
static int (* const externalFunction)(int x) = (int (*)(int)) 0x80002001;
int fun ( int x )
{
    return((* externalFunction)(x)+3);
}
```

but the hardcoded address is in the code not the linker script if that matters, was trying to solve that and couldnt.

```
08000000 <fun>:
 8000000:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
 8000002:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (8000010 <fun+0x10>)
 8000004:   f000 f806   bl  8000014 <fun+0x14>
 8000008:   3003        adds    r0, #3
 800000a:   bc10        pop {r4}
 800000c:   bc02        pop {r1}
 800000e:   4708        bx  r1
 8000010:   80002001    andhi   r2, r0, r1
 8000014:   4718        bx  r3
 8000016:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

I prefer the assembly solution for something like this to force the exact instruction I want.  Naturally if you had linked in the external function it would/should have just worked (there are some exceptions but gnu is getting really good at resolving the to and from arm/thumb for you in the linker).

I dont see it as a gnu bug actually, but instead they need a way in the linker script to declare that variable as a thumb function address rather than just some generic linker defined variable (likewise as an arm function address).  Just like .thumb_func does (or a longer function/procedure declaration)

```
.word branchto

.thumb
.globl branchto
branchto:
    bx r0

 8000018:   0800001c    stmdaeq r0, {r2, r3, r4}

0800001c <branchto>:
 800001c:   4700        bx  r0


.word branchto

.thumb
.thumb_func
.globl branchto
branchto:
    bx r0

 8000018:   0800001d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4}

0800001c <branchto>:
 800001c:   4700        bx  r0
```

by just reading the gnu linker documentation there may be hope to get what you want

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text0 0x08000000 : { so.o }
    .text1 0x08002000 (NOLOAD) : { ex.o }
}
```

ex.o comming from a dummy function to make everyone happy

```
int externalFunction ( int x )
{
    return(x);
}

08000000 <fun>:
 8000000:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
 8000002:   f001 fffd   bl  8002000 <externalFunction>
 8000006:   3003        adds    r0, #3
 8000008:   bc10        pop {r4}
 800000a:   bc02        pop {r1}
 800000c:   4708        bx  r1
```

and the NOLOAD keeps the dummy function out of the binary.

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf -O srec --srec-forceS3 so.srec

S00A0000736F2E7372656338
S3150800000010B501F0FDFF033010BC02BC0847C0461E
S315080000104743433A2028474E552920362E322E305C
S31508000020004129000000616561626900011F000046
S3150800003000053454000602080109011204140115CA
S31008000040011703180119011A011E021E
S70500000000FA
```

note it wasnt perfect there was extra garbage that got pulled in, perhaps symbols

```
08000000 <fun>:
 8000000:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
 8000002:   f001 fffd   bl  8002000 <externalFunction>
 8000006:   3003        adds    r0, #3
 8000008:   bc10        pop {r4}
 800000a:   bc02        pop {r1}
 800000c:   4708        bx  r1
 800000e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000010:   3a434347    
 8000014:   4e472820    
 8000018:   36202955    
 800001c:   302e322e    
 8000020:   00294100    
 8000024:   65610000    
 8000028:   00696261    
 800002c:   00001f01    
 8000030:   54340500    
 8000034:   08020600    
 8000038:   12010901    
 800003c:   15011404    
 8000040:   18031701    
 8000044:   1a011901
```

which you can see in the srec, but the 0x08002000 code is not there so your actual external function will get called.

I would go with just making the instruction you want or function pointers with an assignment if you dont want any asm.

Answer (score 0):

The other comments/answers using long branches do work, but it would still be nice to have a direct BL call and avoid the unnecessary load.

I believe I've found a workaround [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/224550). Create a dummy file (let's call it `ext.c`) with:

```
__attribute__((naked)) int externalFunction(int x){}
```

Compile this file to `ext.o` (same way as you compile `multiply.c`). This generates a dummy object file with a correctly decorated function symbol for `externalFunction`, whose address gets overridden by the linker script, resulting in the desired BL instruction:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <multiply>:
 8000000:       b510            push    {r4, lr}
 8000002:       4348            muls    r0, r1
 8000004:       f001 fffc       bl      8002000 <externalFunction>
 8000008:       bc10            pop     {r4}
 800000a:       bc02            pop     {r1}
 800000c:       4708            bx      r1
 800000e:       46c0            nop                     ; (mov r8, r8)
```

Comment: Note that if the destination of the BL instruction isn't within +/-16M in your real case the linker will just replace it with a long branch anyways.